# Tapir with Akka HTTP file upload - Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http, tapir

I use tapir + akka http for the service. One of the endpoints downloads files.

```
val load
      : Endpoint[Source[ByteString, Any], Any, Any, AkkaStreams] =
    endpoint
      .post
      .in("load")
      .in(streamBody(AkkaStreams)(
        Schema(Schema.schemaForByteArray.schemaType),
        CodecFormat.OctetStream()
      ))
      .out(???)
```

Gettin warn

> Sending an 2xx 'early' response before end of request was received

How do I handle this using tapir?

Comment: Your endpoint input is a stream/file? Not the output. That's what you want?

Comment: Also share with us the full endpoint description: what's the output? And how are you calling your endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

This is this issue with akka-http: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2455

Do you use `Source` of chunks in your code? Akka-http consumes messages, when `LastChunk` is consumed, it sends response, not even consuming `MessageEnd` which comes after `LastChunk`.

`MessageEnd` is not consumed, `messageEndPending` is set to `true` hence the warning about early response.

I worked around it by filtering the `LastChunk` and concatenating it to the end of the stream - after `MessageEnd` and thus forcing akka-http to consume `MessageEnd`.

Comment: Are you saying this a bug in the Akka HTTP Tapir integration then? Worth opening an issue on Tapir?

Comment: No, it's a bug in akka-http. Tapir could workaround it, but still - a bug is in akka-http